# Propagate button onclick of custom arrayadapter in my activity

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

My activity has a ListView that has a custom ArrayAdapter.
On my ArrayAdapter i have an image, a bunch of textboxes and a button.

On the getView of the adapter i get my button and set setOnClickListener. From the click listener i can get the index of the clicked item.

Now my problem is that i want to propagate that information to my main activity, where i want to handle my button click.
I can save the index information in a static var, but i still don't know how to fire an event in my activity.

How do i do that?

I'm 6 days new to Android so, thanks
iggy

Code:

My Activity:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{
...
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvxml);
    myList = new MyCustomArrayAdapter(this, myAnotherClassObject);
    myListView .setAdapter(myList);
    ...
    }
}
```

Now in my Adapter

```
public class MyCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<myAnotherClass> {
...
....
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         Button b = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myButtonInListView);
         b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 doStuff;
             }
     });
    }
}
```

I need to somehow fire a buttonclick from my main activity, but without loosing the possibility to read the index clicked in the list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved it somehow. It's probably not the way to do it but it works.

I save my activity in a static var.

```
Button b = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myButtonInListView);
b.setTag(position);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             int i = (Integer) v.getTag();
             myStaticVarRep.myActivity.myMethod(i);
         }
 });
```

Comment: what is this myStaticVarRep in ur code. myStaticVarRep.myActivity.myMethod(i);

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative and, what I think to be, more elegant solution.

Firstly, in your `MyCustomArrayAdapter` class, define an interface:

```
public interface MyCustomRowButtonListener{
  void onCustomRowButtonClick(MyAnotherClass selectedItem, int position, View view);
}
```

Create an member variable of `MyCustomRowButtonListener` in your `ArrayAdapter`

```
public class MyCustomArrayAdapter{

  private MyCustomRowButtonListener mRowButtonListener;
  //....
}
```

and add a parameter for the listener in the constructor

```
public MyCustomArrayAdapter(Context context, MyCustomRowButtonListener listener){

  mContext = context;
  mRowButtonListener = listener;

}
```

in the getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     Button b = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myButtonInListView);
     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             mRowButtonListener.onCustomRowButtonClick(getItem(position),position,b);
         }
 });
}
```

and in your activity:

```
myList = new MyCustomArrayAdapter(this, myAnotherClassObject,this);
```

Now let your activity implement MyCustomRowButtonListener

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements MyCustomRowButtonListener{
...
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvxml);
    myList = new MyCustomArrayAdapter(this, myAnotherClassObject,this);
    myListView .setAdapter(myList);
    ...
    }
}

public void onCustomRowButtonClick(MyAnotherClass selectedItem, int position, View view){
    Toast.makeText(this,"You have selected "+selectedItem,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Struggled with this for hours

Answer (score 0):

The index ist the `position` variable.
Ist has to be final to use it here

> public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

You can inform your `Activity` with a listener-interface.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume your code looks a little like this.

```
public class <Your Class> ... implements OnClickListener{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        .
        .
        .
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

To handle button click events, you need to have an onClick method that looks like this.

```
public void onClick(View v){
    <Handle your button click in here>
}
```

Whenever you click your button, it'll invoke the onClick method. That is where you would manipulate your static var, fire off other methods, etc. I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I guess i wasn't clear. I've edited my post to better explain my problem, with some code.